# mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory - how do I find out who's complaining?

Tags: linux, process, logs, gentoo

mmap() failed is popping up in my .xsession-errors in bursts. But there's no indication about what application it is failing with. How do I look into this after it has happened? I usually discover the failures only when I occasionally switch to my "tail -f .logs/*" workspace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) for this sort of thing.

- First, set up your system.  You need SystemTap, headers corresponding to your running kernel, and debug symbols for the same.  On Debian, getting it working is something like:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install systemtap
  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
  sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbg
  ```

  It can be a bit tricky to get it to work, because the kernel headers and symbols need to match your running kernel exactly.  Hopefully it's straightforward on Gentoo.
- Then, save this file as `mmap.stp`:

  ```
  #! /usr/bin/env stap
  # -*- systemtap -*-

  global last_args

  probe syscall.mmap2 {
          last_args[tid()] = argstr;
  }

  probe syscall.mmap2.return {
          errno = errno_p(returnval())
          if (errno != 0) {
                  printf("%s[%d] mmap2(%s) failed: %d (%s)\n",
                         execname(), pid(), last_args[tid()],
                         errno, errno_str(errno));
          }
  }

  probe begin {
          printf("begin\n");
  }

  probe end {
          printf("end\n");
  }
  ```
- Run it with

  ```
  sudo stap mmap.stp
  ```

After it compiles and prints `begin`, It will watch every `mmap()` system call and save its arguments.  If an error occurs, you'll get output that includes the program name, process ID, arguments, and error code.  For example, running this nonsensical program:

```
int main() {
        mmap(1,-1,123,0,1,0);
}
```

gives the SystemTap output:

```
test[9601] mmap2(0x1, 4294967295, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_SEM|0x70, 0x0, 1, 0) failed: 22 (EINVAL)
```

Comment: This answer is awesome of course. I should report though that in my case it was a simple case of Thundebird hitting 2.7G VIRT barrier on x86. Time to take pain pills and start converting to amd64.